# How To disable 1 item from select box list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Select Box code

```
td = select_tag :rule, rule_option(params[:rule]), class: 'form-control search_text'
```

```
def rule_option(team_id)
    options_for_select([['All Teams', '']]
     + @site.active_teams
            .select('id, team_type_id, other_name')
            .active.includes(:team_type)
            .map { |t| [t.name, t.id] }
            .reject{ |t| t[0].blank? }, team_id) 
     + options_for_select([['Archived Teams', '']] 
     + @site.teams
            .select('id, team_type_id, other_name')
            .where(active: false)
            .where(deleted: false)
            .includes(:team_type)
            .map { |t| [t.name, t.id] }
            .reject{ |t| t[0].blank? }, team_id)

end
```

I want "Archived Teams" to be displayed as a greyed out non-selectable text entry
[image: To display like the image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify values to be disabled in the option tags by passing the `:disabled` option to the `options_for_select` helper. This can either be a single value or an array of values to be disabled.

Example:

`options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], selected: "Free", disabled: "Super Platinum")`